# Multiple lines from different files printing

Tags: python

I got two lists of items,one in text and one in numbers. I want to print them together somewhat like this

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

and so on. but here is a piece of my code :

```
f = open("file1","r+")
VALORINUMAR=f.readlines()
g=open("test.txt",'r+')
VALORITEXT=g.readlines()
a,k=0
for a,k in range(0,50):
print(VALORITEXT[a],VALORITEXT[k])
```

I'm getting this error in

```
<module>
 a,k=0
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: This obviously isn't a piece of your _real_ code, because it's missing at least one `"` and will just be a `SyntaxError`. Please post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Meanwhile, it's almost certainly that in your _real_ code, you're doing something you aren't doing in this example, like reassigning the loop variable to the file object (the equivalent of `k = g` inside the `for k…` in this code), or just using the wrong variable (like `liniute[g]` instead of `liniute[k]`). But, since the code you posted doesn't _have_ that mistake, we can't tell you exactly where it is in your real code.

Comment: I posted the part of the code that works in the first part,and I said that I want it to get printed on the same line,the first part prints the first file then the 2nd. i do not know how to merge the prints together. i searched around and saw that you can use two variables for a loop but it's not working for me. sorry for the confusion

Comment: Well, there are two different errors in your second code, but neither one is anything remotely like the error you claim you're getting.

Comment: following your advice i decided to rewrite it.now i'm getting in <module>
    a,k=0
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. edited the first post with the new code.

Comment: That's not my advice. I explained that `for a, k in range(0, 50):` is just as illegal as `a, k = 1`. So I'm not sure why you'd think that means `a, k = 0` would be any more legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` will be useful.

```
f = open("file1", "r")
g = open("test.txt", "r")
for fline, gline in zip(f, g):
    print(fline.strip(), gline.strip())
```

(Hat tip to mpolednik, since this is just a simplification of his idea.)

Comment: It has the benefit of having very few moving parts, even if you don't actually know what `zip` does.

Answer (score 1):

If `liniute[k]` is raising a `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not _io.TextIOWrapper`, that means that `k` is a file object, not an integer.

The code you posted doesn't actually do that. If your real code does, you've almost certainly done one of two things:

```
for k in range (0,50):
    print(liniute[g]) # oops, g instead of k

for k in range (0,50):
    # long complicated body that does lots of stuff...
    k = open("otherfile") # oops, reused k to mean two things
    # ...
    print(liniute[k])
```

Using meaningful variable names instead of random one-letter names makes errors like this a lot harder to create, and a lot easier to debug.

---

Meanwhile, this code:

```
for a, k  in range (0,50):
print(lines[a],liniute[k])
```

… does have two errors in it, but still not the error you posted.

First, there's an obvious `IndentationError`.

Second, `range(0, 50)` iterates over integers, not pairs of integers, so you can't assign each one to `a, k`. It's just like writing `a, k = 1`.

But you really don't need two separate variables here. Just use the same variable twice:

```
for a in range(0, 50):
    print(lines[a], liniute[a])
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you're trying to do is just pairing the files. If that is the case, generators come in handy.

```
def text_generator():
    with open('secondfile.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line.rstrip('\n')

with open('firstfile.txt', 'r+') as f:
    generator = text_generator()
    for fline in f:
        print(fline.rstrip('\n'), next(generator))
```

Extra care needs to be taken with newlines: both files most probably contain them and print implicitly also adds one. We therefore have to strip these to have a nice output.